# How to get the values using jquery for loop and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, for-loop

here i want to print the absentList array values in loop using jquery and ajax,

> Here is my AJAX code

```
    $.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     url :"admin_getabsentlist",
     data: $('form#subjectForm').serialize(),
     success: function(data) {
     var res=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
     console.log(res);
    if(res['status']=='Success'){

   $.each( res['data'], function( key, value ) {

      alert(value.absentList);

    });
    }else{
        alert('else part');
    }
     },
     error:function(exception){
     alert('Exeption:'+exception);
    }
})
```

here if i am printing the values like console.log(res); means i am getting the results like

> I am getting results

```
object {status: "Success", data: Object}
data:Object
absentList:Array(2)
0:'Kani'
1:'yuvi'
```

now i want to print the **absentList** values so iam using forloop like this

> Forloop

```
 if(res['status']=='Success'){

   $.each( res['data'], function( key, value ) {

      alert(value.absentList);

    });
```

but here i am getting the absentList values i am getting undefined ,please tell me anyone

> Expected results

in alert box i want print the values of **Kani** and **yuvi**

Comment: Iterate `absentList` i.e `$.each(res.data.absentList, function (key, value) {
 alert(value);
});
 `

Answer (score 1):

Just access the result object property containing data in your each loop

```
if(res['status']=='Success'){    
      $.each(res['data'].absentList, function( key, value ) {
          alert(value);
      });
}
```

Comment: @subikshanM Welcome :)

Comment: @mr this answer not suitable for me